# "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format" while creating table in windows azure

Tags: azure

I am getting the exception "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format." from TableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(TableName); I am using development storage.

Comment: What is the table name you're trying to create?

Comment: there is no problem with the table name, as the table name is "sessions".

Comment: I tripped over this error: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18106272/10245 which had the above error hiding inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Understanding the Table Service Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx) article. Most probably you are either providing an invalid table name, or you are using unsupported version of the Table Service. The lates [version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894041.aspx) of Table Service is not yet supported on Development Fabric.

Comment: I am creating a table with the name "sessions". the above code is working properly when i am using azure environment. i am getting this problem while i am using development environment(emulator). i installed latest version of emulator manually.

Comment: Well, if your queries are working with real Azure Storage, then use it. As I said, there are some features for the Table Services that are not supported in the development storage.