# azure local storage emulator issue 400 bad request

Tags: windows, azure, sdk, storage, emulation

I could not find this one on the site. It may be trivial, but the error message is pretty misleading.

When you try out things with the azure sdk and the local emulators (storage and compute emulators) while debugging, you may get the following error during initialization of those emulators:

The process cannot access the file because it is used by an another process.

Moreover, if you want to test things from the code and you want to access the blob storage emulator, you may get 400 Bad request as a result.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9122920/10245 - has the inner message I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure this. Open the "DSServiceLDB.exe.config" file under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devstore".

Inside the file, tweak the values in this section:

```
<services>
    <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:10000/"/>
    <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:10001/"/>
    <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:10002/"/>
</services>
```